# Difference between multi processors vs multi cores

Tags: .net, multithreading

My application runs on 4 simultaneous threads. I can make those threads as multi threads as well as single thread (MTA / STA). When I declare them STA the result is faster than when I declare them MTA. Its written in vb.net and i am using 2003 server (windows) standard edition as operating system, The processor is single and quad core.

What should I do to make it faster?

I can increase number of processor to 2, or I can use hexcore/ octal core processor instead.
Can anyone suggest?

Thanks.

Comment: FYI: MTA/STA are COM threading apartments. See http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms693344(v=vs.85).aspx

Answer (score 2):

Multiple processors means that the motherboard has multiple processors chips on it. Multicore means that a chip has multiple processing units on it. Multiple processors will have different front side busses and multiple cores will generally share L2 cache. Both of these have advantages depending on what you are doing.

For the second part of your question, the answer is less concrete. If the work you are doing is not that complicated, the overhead of multiple threads could outweigh the performance gains. Also, if your threads are trying to access the same shared memory, locking will slow them down. Your threads could also be bottle-necked doing IO to the disk. Without information about what you are actually doing, it is hard to say what is your problem and how to proceed further. Buying a newer, faster, bigger processor will speed things up, but it doesn't address the issue of why you think your program is not running faster. Spend some time working with the code before you start throwing money at the problem.

Comment: "Spend some time working with the code before you start throwing money at the problem". While I agree, I think it should be noted that _spending time working with the code_ **is also** _throwing money at the problem_. Sometimes - very rearly - a bigger/better machine is the faster & cheaper solution.

Comment: @BinaryWorrier: True. It's a balance between a solution that will work fast and now versus a solution that might take time, could cause errors, but could also solve the root cause of slowdown.

Answer (score 0):

MTA should be slower than STA because, as its name shows, *multiple* number of threads may be running in that apartment, so a lot of things have to involve locking.  Even if you only have one single thread running there, the locking must still be done, thus incurring overhead.  Therefore, 4 threads running on 4x STA will be faster than 4 threads running on 4x MTA, even if the threads and apartments are matched one-to-one.  You are not gaining anything by making your apartment mode MTA if you don't intend to run more than one thread on the object.

Add more processors and/or cores will help you as your four threads are likely to be running on different cores.

However, adding more cores than the number of threads will *not* add performance, since one thread runs only on one core.  In your example, your four threads should run on 4 cores (whether they belong to the same processor).  Add one or two cores for system programs (assuming you don't run anything else) and drivers, and you probably max out.  Adding more cores will not help as those cores may be idle unless you increase you thread count.

Other things affect your concurrency performance as well: if you have a shared resource that is a contention point among your threads, and your threads are waiting for locks on this resource all the time, then adding more cores may not help you because your bottleneck is in accessing the shared resource and threads are just running idle waiting.  In this case, upgrading to a faster CPU (in terms of clock speed) will be faster as it increases the speed that your contented resources are being released.

Adding processors typically will be faster than adding cores on the same processor, as different cores share internal resources within a single processor, and if one core is using a resource, other cores block.  However, I've heard about situations that adding cores are faster when multiple processors have to access the same memory locations and that same information can be stored in a cache inside one processor, shared among all its cores.